# Google pointing to old GitHub repository

Tags: google-search, github

I have a GitHub repository called phpat, but Google's first result points to an old repo (404 error)

How much time does it take for Google to update this?

Is there any way to inform the search engine about the change?

Comment: I see Google results https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQqPS.png for GitHub repositories form nbadji and rgueye.   Neither of them are 404 not found errors.  The rgueye one has only a .gitignore file, but the other one has lots of stuff.

Comment: If you search `phpat` with my username `carlosas` you will see the old one but not the one I mentioned in the question. Sorry for the missunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems it's just a matter of time.

The spider visited and updated the information after 4 days.

Comment: Github is also supposed to redirect from the old location to the new location automatically: [Repository redirects are here! - The GitHub Blog](https://github.blog/2013-05-16-repository-redirects-are-here/)  I'm not sure why it was showing a 404 for you to begin with.  Maybe it takes some time for GitHub to realize it moved and put the redirects in place.

Comment: It was a new repository, and the previous one was deleted. That's why it seemed weird to me seeing the old one (broken) but no news of the new one for that many days.